# express-session save the session only in the call time

Tags: node.js, session, localhost

i have server in node.js and client side in angular Both of them runnning on localhost
every time when user log in to my site i save his details in the express-session
and after in the calls from the client side to the server.
i check if the user is connect, if his details are in session but
both when the user is logged in and when not the session is empty

in this code i save the session.
the router:

```
router.post('/login/check', async (req, res) => {
    let result = await createLoginSession(req.session,req.body.name);
    console.log(req.session);
}
```

the module:

```
 createLoginSession = (session,name) => {
    if(!session) return;
    let ageSession = 1000*60*60*24*30; 
    session.cookie.expires = new Date(Date.now() + ageSession);
    session.cookie.maxAge = ageSession;
    session.clientType = 'STANDART_SINGLE';
    session.name = name;
   
};
```

it's work well i see the session in the log
but in the next call to the server i log the session and it was empty

```
router.post('/details',async (req, res) => {
   console.log(req.session);
});
```

i think that it's because the server and client run on localhost everytime there is new sessionId
what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Here I have two solution which ever works for you :

1. use function from library if you are using Express for example :cookie session or express session for more information on both you can read their documentation.(recommended if using express)
2. Now this method is not the best way to do it but it will work fine.
   save the data from req.session in global array lets say sesData or object and when new req is made copy this data to req.session and as in JS object when assigned to another variable it is copied by reference so changes in req.session for that call will be reflected on sesData and for next call you can again copy its data to req.session (to make it better use middleware to maintain session).